# html,css,jsで構成されているファイルをサーバーにアップロードしたがhtmlしか反映されない

Tags: html

タイトルのようにhtml, css, jsで構成されているファイルをアップロードしたがhtmlしか反映されない問題を解決したいです。
また、画像も反映されません。

思いついた原因は

- 相対パスが間違っているため開けない。
- アップロードされていると思い込んでいるが実際はアップロードされていない。
- 何かしら必要なことを行っていない

これらの解決方法として、以下のことを実行しました

1. htmlファイルだけでなく、css,img,jsファイルをデスクトップに入っている状態のままアップロードした。
   これはコードを書いているときの状態、つまり、デスクトップやgooglechromeでは実際に開けることを確認しているためパスが間違っているとは考えにくい。
2. ググっていろいろな人の質問を確認して試してみたが反応なし。

唯一反応があったのは相対パスを `../css/ファイル名` としていたところを `ファイル名` に変更したことでcssが反映された。
しかし、jsやimgに対して同様に行っても反応しなかったことを考えると残っていたキャッシュが反応したのではないかと思った。

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0″> <title>iSara模写</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/iSara模写.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/iSara模写responsive.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/slick.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/slick-theme.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6b65e275a4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> </head> <body> 
  <header>
    <div class="head">
      <div class="header-left">
        <img src="https://isara.life/wp-content/themes/isara_v2/img/isaralogo.png" alt="iSara">
        <p>バンコクのノマドエンジニア育成講座</p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn">
         <a href="#skip"><p>お問い合わせ / 資料請求はこちら</p> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn0">
        <img src="https://isara.life/wp-content/themes/isara_v2/img/form.png" alt="">
      <a href="#skip"> <p>資料請求</p></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

<div class="main">
  <div class="main-img">
    <img class="img1" src="https://isara.life/wp-content/themes/isara_v2/img/main.jpg" alt="">
    <h2>プログラミングで<span class="br2"></span><span class="br">人生の安定を手にいれよう</span></h2>
    <img  class="img2" src="../img/isaralogolarge.png" alt="">
    <h3>バンコクのノマドエンジニア育成講座<span class="br2"></span><span class="br">iSara[イサラ]</span></h3>
 </div>
、、、略、、、
<script src="../js/slick.min.js"> </script> <script src="../js/iSara模写.js"> </script> </body>
```

こんな感じで二日間くらい進展がないので意見をいただけたら嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 画像を直接URLで指定してアクセスした場合はどうなりますか？ / 少なくともどんな HTML なのかは中身を見せてもらわないとアドバイスが付きづらいと思います。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: 画像をurlから開くときちんと表示されます。また、css,jsファイルもurlから開くとコードが表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

「htmlファイルだけでなく、css,img,jsファイルをデスクトップに入っている状態のままアップロードした」ということは、htmlファイル、imgファイル、jsファイルは同じディレクトリにあるという事だとおもいます。
これは、「相対パスを ../css/ファイル名 としていたところを ファイル名 に変更したことでcssが反映された」と書かれている事と一致します。

では、imgファイルとjsファイルは、どこにあるのでしょうか？　htmlと同じフォルダーにあるなら、"../img/isaralogolarge.png"を"isaralogolarge.png"に、"../js/iSara模写.js"を"iSara模写.js"に変更してみてください。

"iSara模写.js"という漢字を含んだファイル名はトラブルの要因です。ファイル名を"iSara模写.js"から"iSaraMosha.js"に変更し、HTMLファイルの中も"iSara模写.js"から"iSaraMosha.js"に変更すると、漢字コードの差異による問題が解決されると思います。